# How to select javascript elements which are generated dynamically based on previous input response?

Tags: javascript, ruby, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an element gets generated (or is displayed) only after an input is entered in previous step and an enter key is hit.
How do we handle such dynamic elements with Selenium Webdriver?

I tried adding explicit waits (wait_until) but face "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up" every time.

```
#Airfares
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"500",:tab

#No of airtickets
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2",:return
```

[image: No. of tickets input box open ups after entering airfare and hitting tab / enter key]

How do we handle such on the fly generated elements?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your code where the problem is occurring?

Comment: @autoKarma, added the code and screenshot for application behavior.

Comment: Thanks--now a bit of the html for the part in question?--Instead of an absolute xpath, you could identify the xpath by some attribute actually in the input field in question. But in order to give more specifics, we'd need to see html corresponding to the part of the page where you've taken the screenshot.

Comment: `<input type="text" class="integer" onchange="setValueSelectorDirty('cpe139');" id="tile363_input" selector="selector" value="">` Thats the htmlbut all these fields are rendered in javascript.

Comment: @autoKarma added html..